# Present Data in Presentation Layer after Removing the Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

Inside of stored procedure you have the code

```
create table #datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into #datatable
exec ('select *
from datatable
where id = 1') 

select * from #datatable
```

I still want to retrieve the data and present it in the software's presentation layer but I still want to remove the temp table in order to reduce performance issue etc.

If I paste the code `DROP TABLE #datatable` after

```
insert into #datatable
exec ('select *
from datatable
where id = 1')
```

Does it gonna work to present the data in the presentation layer after removing the temp table?

Thanks!

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14bbc/1/1

Comment: Are you asking if data can be read from a table after having dropped the table?

Comment: The goal is to retrieve the data from stored procedure and I want to remove the temp table after I have used it.

Comment: You already have an answer, but i'm curious as to why you are inserting into your temp table then selecting the same data back out? You could just get rid of your temp table completely and your stored procedure would just have a single select x from y statement inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just drop the table after select .becoz **it no use to drop table without showing output from temp table used inside the SP**

```
create table #datatable (id int,
                        name varchar(100),
                        email varchar(10),
                        phone varchar(10),
                        cellphone varchar(10),
                        none varchar(10)                        
                       );

insert into #datatable
exec ('select *
from datatable
where id = 1') 

select * from #datatable

drop table #datatable
```

Comment: I don't understand, Will the software retrieve the data from stored procedure after using drop table or not?

Comment: yes.it will retrive value from sp.the thing is we have to drop table after select statement of that table

Comment: Please read Simone's statement. His statement is totally different from mine. I'm confuzed.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You say you have a reason for doing it so ignore my answer below. Answering whether you can drop the temp table then yes you can, and your data **will** still be returned by your stored procedure. You can just put the

```
DROP TABLE #datatable
```

line in after your

```
select * from #datatable
```

line and you'll be fine. It's good practice to clean up after yourself, even though your temp table will only have a lifetime of the current user session.

Also, in one of your comments you say "I want to remove the data temp because the this SP will be used many time." Local temporary tables are not accessible by other users, and their data does not persist between user sessions, so no other call to this stored procedure would access the information from the temp table that is created within the first call.

---

Initial Answer:

I don't see why you are using a temporary table at all here? Unless you are doing other processing than what is in your fiddle etc then why can't you just use a simple select? There is no need to use a temporary table or EXEC a select into it for this case. Obviously you may have just simplified your question in that case just ignore this answer but if not then your SP would just be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procname] 
(
  @id int
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT id
       name,
       email,
       phone,
       cellphone,
       none
FROM datatable
WHERE id = @id

END
```

Comment: There is a reason why I'm asking this question.

Answer (score -1):

If you type the drop table after the insert statement you won't be able to get any result from the subsequent select: you dropped a table and SQL will say it doesn't know the table you are asking for. Get the data and then drop the table

Comment: Simply explaination, The software won't retrieve retrieve the data in the presentation layer after using drop table?

Comment: No, it can't, even if everything is inside a stored procedure the data are returned by the select statement, so if you had previously removed the table you're going to get data from, the stored procedure is not capable of getting them. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14bbc/5 let you see the SQL doesn't the table after you dropped

Comment: you use drop table and then you present the data. In my case it would be present the data with select * and then drop temptable.

Comment: The goal is to retrieve the the data from a stored procedure in my software in the presentaiton layer but still I want to remove the data temp because the this SP will be used many time.

Comment: I suppose you're talking about some other kind of projects when you say presentation layer. In any case looking only at SQL level the only way is to get data is to drop the table after having performed the select; this doesn't mean the stored procedure stops from running after the select, but only that it is going to output some data and then continue with its body code. You could also have many select inside a stored procedure to get many outputs. The SP stops only at its end.